# Can we use inbuilt functions in update query where condition inside a cursor loop?

Tags: mysql, function, phpmyadmin

Hi i am using a "timestampdiff" function in an update query where condition as below. It works fine when i run it as a separate query.
But when i use the same inside a cursor loop in procedure it is not working. can anyone please help me to resolve this?

```sql
OPEN QUZ_CUR;
LOOPROWS : LOOP

    IF FINISHED = 1 THEN
        CLOSE QUZ_CUR;
        LEAVE LOOPROWS;
    END IF;
    
    FETCH QUZ_CUR INTO ATTEMPT_ID,QUIZ_ID,QUIZ_DT;
    
    UPDATE SIGARAM_QUIZATTEMPTCOUNT 
    SET STATUS = 'Time out' 
    WHERE (timestampdiff(minute,QUIZ_DT,now()) > (SELECT TIMELIMIT 
                                                  FROM CMS.CMS_ASSESSMENT 
                                                  WHERE ID = QUIZ_ID)) 
      AND ID = ATTEMPT_ID;
    
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Provide DDL for SIGARAM_QUIZATTEMPTCOUNT, INSERT INTO with some sample data and desired final data state.

Comment: How does phpMyAdmin fit in to this, are you using the phpMyAdmin procedure editor to create the procedure? Are you manually running the SQL to create the procedure?

Comment: Yes. I am using phpMyAdmin procedure editor to create procedures